# Google Table Chart: Date Format

Tags: google-visualization

I am returning data to the chart using JSON.
I've managed to format the date for the x-axiz of the Line Chart, using;

```
var options = {
            hAxis: {
                         format: ' dd MMM yy'
                    },
}
```

But I need help doing the same for a Table Chart where one of the columns should be of date format.

At the moment it is displaying "/Date(1372761341103)/"
How do I format this option? 
As I understand it, the "options" variable setting is not available for the Table Chart.
Also, when I add my columns, setting my 'Date' column's data type to 'date' doesn't work...no chart is returned.

**This is my code currently:**

```
         function drawChart3() {
          $.get('/MyMall/GetAdRunData', {},
            function (data) {

                /* Add data */
                var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable()
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Id');
                tdata.addColumn('string','Date');
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Opens');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tdata.addRow([data[i].Id, data[i].Date, data[i].Opens]);
                }

                /* Draw chart */
                var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_adRun'));
                //var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
                //var monthYearFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: "MMM yyyy" });
                monthYearFormatter.format(tdata, 0);
                formatter.addRange(-1, 1, 'white', 'orange');
                formatter.addRange(0, 2, 'red', '#33ff33');
                formatter.addRange(1, 10, 'red', 'pink');
                formatter.format(tdata, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
                chart.draw(tdata, { allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: false });
            }
         )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way...

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(data[i].Date.substr(6)));
                    tdata.addRow([data[i].Id, date, data[i].Opens]);
                }
```